# Angular Error - Can't interpolate: (device.osVersion) Android 4.0.3

Tags: angularjs, appgyver, supersonic

So I am running the Supersonic demo template on my Android phone, and I keep getting this error that is preventing the app from loading the page:

> Can't interpolate: {{device.osVersion | strReplace:'_':'.'}}
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'replace' of undefined

Page setup tutorial page: [this link](http://docs.appgyver.com/supersonic/tutorial/first-mile/)

Screenshot of debug console:

[image]

This is the raw untouched demo from AppGyver, so it should work out of the box! This does work on my iPad though so it seems to be an error with Android. I am running the app through the AppGyver Scanner on my phone.

Android version: 4.0.3

This is what the app screen looks like (the black space being the error as there should be text and buttons there):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The error you've had is not from the app, it is from your browser. It should not affect your app in any way.

To fix the problem of appgyver's steroids, I have a hacky solution:

1) Locate the steroids's node_module

Mine's running on windows and installed with `npm install -g`, located at

```
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\steroids\node_modules\steroids-connect\dist\__connect\
```

2) Edit the `steroids.connect.js` file:

Find `{{device.osVersion | strReplace:'_':'.'}}` and replace it with `{{device.osVersion}}`